# Auto Contact Enrollment, Sitecore 9.0.2

Tags: marketing-automation, list-manager

Is there a way I can auto enroll a list of contacts, created in list manager to a campaign ? I see 9.1 has an option to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the release notes for 9.1 Initial, it calls out "Marketing Automation now supports seeding a plan from a contact list. All the contacts from the list are enrolled in the plan."

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/91/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2091%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes

The wording there would suggest that up until then, this wasn't possible without custom code to look after it..

Looks like Mark has a blog post about how that can be done :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - I wrote a blog on this - [Troubleshooting Sitecore Marketing Automation Plan Enrollment](https://medium.com/@markgibbons25/troubleshooting-sitecore-marketing-automation-plan-enrollment-1b8461e802b0) - relevant excerpt below:

**How can I trigger contacts to be processed by the Automation Engine?**

Basically — they need to be submitted to xConnect somehow. A few options here:

- You could “touch” them somehow — for example if you’re syncing via Data Exchange Framework then it will create / update your contacts which will submit them to xConnect whether they are changed or not. Or you could create your own admin page / background process that will do something similar. Note that the contact will require at least one Facet or Interaction event to be associated with it for it to be added to the AutomationPool.
- In Sitecore 9.1+ you can enroll contacts directly from a Contact List. This is a manual operation with a few clicks.
- Write some code to enroll contacts via the Marketing Automation Operations API

As you mentioned, the 2nd option isn't available to you on 9.0 so you'll be best served changing your marketing plan entry activity to check if the contact is part of the list, and then either adding the contacts to the list manually after that, or writing some code to trigger them being processed by XConnect (e.g. a dummy contact facet update).

Comment: Thanks Mark ! This is all very helpful. Keen on trying bullet #3. Will update this once I  have something that works :-)